# what is the max numbers of inputs for `keras.model(input)` instead of `keras.model.predict(input)`

Tags: tensorflow, keras, model, predict, batchsize

In [this documentation of `Keras.model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict), it describe the differences between using `keras.model.predict(input)` and `keras.model(input)`, stating that the latter is a better suit for small numbers of inputs.

My question is, what is the max numbers of inputs for `keras.model(input)`?

---

### Revision 12-20-2022

"For small numbers of inputs that fit in one batch, directly use `__call__()` for faster execution, e.g., `model(x)`"

The quote is as above. `learner` and `Dr. snoopy` said that I might misunderstand the meaning of "small numbers of inputs that fit in one batch".

Comment: Smaller numbers is a relative term. Nothing concrete I think.

Comment: @mss Do you know what it's relative to? If I have inputs of 71 numbers and outputs of 2, is that small? What if the numbers of inputs are 300?

Comment: maximum your GPU can accommodate. With `predict`, you can predict any large data with batching (just the batch needs to fit in GPU), but not the case with the direct call method.

Comment: @V.M So does that mean with a large enough GPU say 3090 24GB, thousands even millions of inputs can be fit into it without calling `predict`?

Comment: NO. thousands and millions of inputs  can be predicted only by the `predict` method using multiple batches, unlike the direct call that can only predict a single batch and max size of a batch depends on GPU size.

Comment: So when predicting a batch of inputs, `model.predict(input)` or `model.predict_on_batch(input)` is required. but if the batch size is one and the input contains thousands or millions of numbers, as long as those numbers fit into the GPU, you can use `model(input)`. right?

Comment: The link you provided does not describe the difference between predict and Input, you completely misinterpreted the documentation.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy In the link it says, "For small numbers of inputs that fit in one batch, directly use __call__() for faster execution, e.g., model(x)"

Comment: I think the title and some parts of the post should be revised to avoid confusion. In particular, "max numbers of inputs for `keras.model(input)`" may be interpreted as max number of input `tensors`, i.e. inputs=[input_1, input_2, ..., input_n]. What about max number of examples to pass to each of `__call__` (or `call`), and `predict`?

Comment: @DavidH.J. That means number of samples, not number of inputs, the problem is the overloaded use of the word inputs.